# How can I checkout password-protected subversion repositories with bitbake?

Tags: svn, https, bitbake

I am having an issue regarding the svn fetcher of OpenEmbedded/bitbake. When I use:

```
svn://PATH/;proto=https;module=trunk
```

or

```
svn://PATH/;proto=https;module=trunk;username=ABC;password=XYZ
```

bitbake won't do anything. It just waits after:

```
NOTE: Fetch
svn://DOMAIN/svn/src/www/home/trunk/resources/tree/src/metadata-input/trunk/;proto=https;module=trunk
Authentication realm: <https://DOMAIN.de:443> svn/src/www
```

I tried typing in my password or username then password but nothing happens.
After I cancel with `Control-C` I get a prompt on the command line:

```
Password for 'USERNAME':
```

Can someone please give me a hint on solving this? Switching to `http` or
`svn+ssh` is not an option in my company.

Answer (score 5):

The parameters should be user= and pswd=, e.g.:

```
svn://PATH/;proto=https;module=trunk;user=bob;pswd=password
```

Answer (score 3):

Under newer versions of `bitbake` provided with [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org), you would make a recipe that looks something like this (line breaks for clarity):

```
SRC_URI= "svn://svn.example.com/svnreponame/trunk/;\
module=HelloWorld;\
protocol=https;\
user=jrandom;\
pswd= \
"
```

Note that "module" is just the name of the directory to check out from subversion's perspective.

I've left the password off so it isn't stored in your source-code control system with the rest of the recipe. If you provide a username without a password in the recipe, subversion will look for cached credentials [in its usual places](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds). Checking out a working copy elsewhere on the machine with the build user should be sufficient to trigger subversion to ask about caching credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a [`.netrc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc) file in your home directory containing the username and password to your server. Bitbake uses `wget` to fetch files, which in turn reads `.netrc` for passwords.

For example, you could add to your `~/.netrc` file a single line:

```
machine example.com login john.smith password ABC123
```

to inform `wget` to login to `example.com` with username `john.smith` and password `ABC123`.